# Setting js object key value to always reference an existing variable

Tags: javascript

I don't know really what to call this idea, but I want to point an object's key to a variable's value. When I do that, though, the object's key value is pointed to a copy of the original value, rather than the original variable itself.

```
let someArr = ['the original array', 1];
const someObj = { 
  theArr: someArr
}

console.log(someObj.theArr)
// ['the original array', 1]

someArr = ['a new array', 2]

console.log(someObj.theArr) 
// ['the original array', 1]
```

So what's happening here is that when the obj is created and the key value is set to `someArr` the value of `someArr` is being copied to the key, but the actual `someArr` array object is not being pointed to.

First, why is this? What is this called? Second, how could I make `someObj.theArr` always stay equal to the value of `someArr`?

Comment: you created a new value and assigned it to a variable, hence the other value is not modified. Thankfully it's not possible to do what try here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what's happening here...why is this?

As zerkms states, there is no way to maintain a reference to an externally scoped variable upon creation of the object literal in JavaScript. When JavaScript creates an object, it gets the value of the variable you've assigned and creates an internal copy of that value.

> What is this called?

In other languages like `C` and its derivatives, indirectly in Java and some others, this would be called a [*pointer assignment* (see #3)](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/). That is not available in JavaScript.

> how could I make `someObj.theArr` always stay equal to the value of `someArr`

The code below uses `set` and `get` from the Class syntax to accomplish your goal. This is one of a few ways to do this. But, **this is not recommended** as it is a poor design. It is never a good idea to disassociate a property and its actual value.

```js
let someArr = ['the original array', 1];

class SomeObj {
  get theArr() {
    return someArr;
  }
  set theArr(arr) {
    theArr = arr;
    someArr = arr;
  }
}

const someObj = new SomeObj();

console.log(someObj.theArr)

someArr = ['a new array', 2]

console.log(someObj.theArr)
```